# What is the DONE_cycle startup option?

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, ise

In ISE, it is possible to select various "Startup Options" for the generate FPGA image by right-clicking "Generate Programming File", selecting "Process Properties", and then clicking "Startup Options". The listed startup options are:

- StartUpClk
- DonePipe
- DONE_cycle
- GTS_cycle
- GWE_cycle
- DriveDone

[This document](http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/isehelp/pp_db_startup_options.htm) gives explanations for `StartUpClk`, `DonePipe` and `DriveDone`. What exactly is the `DONE_cycle` startup option? (And while we're at it, what are `GTS_cycle` and `GWE_cycle`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the DONE option, it is the event that drives the DONE pin high - for more info on this, see "Sequence of Events" in the Spartan-X Configuration Guide (I'm looking at the Spartan-3 version here, as I happen to be working with one, but I'm sure there will be a similar document for Spartan-6. EDIT - yes there is, it's on page 76 of the [Spartan-6 configuration guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug380.pdf))